# Ident authentication failed for user "ckan_default"

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, ckan

I'm trying to get CKAN (latest - 2.8.1) running on RHEL 7 with Apache SOLR 7.4, Postgresql 9.2.23 and all the other requirements as whatever is the latest through yum.

I have no issue creating the ckan_default user, and the database. But, when I get to this step:

```
paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
```

I get an authentication error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "ckan_default"
```

I thought perhaps I entered the password badly, but I've blown away postgres twice and very carefully entered the ckan_default password.

All the prereqs are working fine, I've tested them independently.

**the crazy thing is, I just set this up a month ago and it was no issue. however I did use CKAN 2.8.0 and SOLR 6.3.0**.  I wanted to use the latest SOLR because 6.3 is unsupported now. This doesn't appear to be a SOLR issue though.

I've searched for a solution thoroughly on here and elsewhere but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: "Some ident servers have a nonstandard option that causes the returned user name to be encrypted, using a key that only the originating machine's administrator knows. This option must not be used when using the ident server with PostgreSQL, since PostgreSQL does not have any way to decrypt the returned string to determine the actual user name." ??

Comment: I also went through this problem, the documentation does not speak about this, however we should change the line: `sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/ckan_default` and put the user and password created for the postgress

Comment: Yes. Changing the password to sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/ckan_default within the /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini file works for me.

This needs to be added to the docs.

Also, at least in Linux:
sudo systemctl restart postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message mentions 'Ident authentication', but it sounds like you want password authentication. Try this for your `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Now restart postgres and try again.

Comment: This did not solve my problem, howeve, changing the line: `sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/ckan_default` and put the **user** and **password** created for the postgress did the trick.